# Replacing deprecated Java method

Tags: java, character-encoding, deprecated, fileutils, ioutils

I have multiple calls that use deprecated methods, such as

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(File file)

org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(InputStream input)
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toInputStream(String input)
```

Now, I do know that these methods are [deprecated](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/deprecated-list.html#method) and with which methods to replace them, for example

```
readFileToString(final File file, final Charset encoding)
```

The difference being that I have to specify an encoding.

Now, because my primary goal is to preserve behaviour while removing the old methods, even if it means preserving bugs/oddities, I want to call the new method such that it works just like the old one.
Reading the Javadoc for the new method reveals

```
* @param encoding the encoding to use, {@code null} means platform default
```

My assumption is now that if I pass `null` as encoding parameter to the new method, it will behave just like the old one. That would imply that the old method always used the platform default. But is there a way to check that?

Comment: Write a test, it should be green and after the refactor should still be green.

Comment: The library is Open Source and most IDEs can download the sources JAR for you. Just check the code of the old methods what they actually do, if it's not clear enough from the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As expected it used the default encoding, [readFileToString](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File)):

> Reads the contents of a file into a String **using the default encoding for the VM**. The file is always closed.

And [IOUtils.toString](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(byte[])):

> Gets the contents of a byte[] as a String **using the default character encoding of the platform**.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Apache Common-io documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File)) says:

> Reads the contents of a file into a String using the default encoding for the VM. The file is always closed.